# Defining constant which can be used by three different project of the same workspace

Tags: android

i have need of a constant which can be used in my three different project of the same workspace.
Actually i want to compare that constant like if(constant==1)
{
do for project1
}
do this
else if(constant==2)
{
do for project2
}
etc....
Is it possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class that holds constant values, e.g.

```
public class MyConstants {
    /** typical value for bar */
    public static final int FOO = -1;
}
```

Or you can use java enums.
Furthermore it is possible to put projects on the build path of other projects.

To do that, right click on your project -> build path -> Configure build path. On the projects tab, eclipse allows you to add specific projects to make your constants class available to other pojects (in your example project 2 and 3).

Aside of that, you should consider to merge projects instead of using three.